# Xcode 6 Refactor : Can only refactor C and Objective C code

Tags: xcode6

I'm getting the above error trying to rename an array. Is there any other way? Trying this

```
Right click on variable -> Refactor -> Rename
```

I'm sure there has to be another way?

Comment: What language are you using? Xcode's refactoring tools do not currently work with Swift code. The refactoring tools work only with C and Objective-C code.

Comment: Then you'll have to use find and replace to rename the array.

Comment: Yes , it's pretty cumbersome :(

Comment: Refactoring is rather complicated. As long as the compiler is fresh meat Apple will likely concentrate on fixing other issues. I'm pretty sure we will see re-factoring naxt year, but likely not earlier.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to rename a local variable within a method or function and just want to rename all occurrences within that function, try this...

Click on the variable and leave your mouse there for a moment.... A down arrow will appear just to the right of the variable name. Click on that down arrow and choose "Edit All In Scope"

[image: Once you click on the variable, notice the small down arrow to the right of it]

[image: Click on Edit All in Scope]

Comment: Or press Cmd + Ctrl + E while the cursors is in the variable.